# PostgreSQL View on a JSONB field object _array_ (with indexing)

Tags: postgresql, indexing, view, jsonb

## Question

How can you make a **PostgreSQL View** based on a **JSONB field object *array***, with **appropriate indexes**? Example below.

1. Conceptually, how should indexing be applied when using with Views and a JSONB array?
2. What is the correct syntax to create the relevant indexes?
3. Is the example view given the correct/optimal way to construct the view for this use case?

## Example

### Table

```
CREATE TABLE "ProductLists"
(
    id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    listName text NOT NULL
    productIds jsonb NOT NULL DEFAULT '[{ productId:0 }]'::jsonb,
)
```

### View (can be changed)

With the following view:

```
SELECT "ProductLists".id AS listId,
    jsonb_array_elements("ProductLists".productIds) ->> 'productId'::text AS productId
   FROM "ProductLists";
```

## Factors

- The JSONB Root is an array, not an object (which is not the case in most indexing examples)
- There will be potentially millions of ProductList items
- The number of productIds in each list will usually be less than 100
- The table will have both high reads and writes
- The view SQL example may or may not be optimal for the purpose, and can be changed

Thanks for any input!

Comment: The most efficient way will be to normalize your data model. http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: What kind of queries are you planning to run on that table? What kind of conditions?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks for your response. Good tip on the quoted identifiers. RE: scenario & kind of queries. Basically, I need to maintain many orderd lists of products. The order matters. Previously I used mapping table with productId, listId and listOrder fields. However, the lists change frequently. A reordering operation for a long list can result in the need to update the `listOrder` value in 100's of rows. I am looking at using the JSONB field to avoid this. One ordered list, neatly stored in a single field.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - (con't from above comment). The most frequenty query is simply getting productIds for a list. The JSONB solution works great here. However, an infrequent operation is to delete a product - in which case there is a need to identify all lists for a given productId. That is the useCase I am trying to solve here, by indexing the JSONB field, and adding a view

Comment: I doubt you'll find an index that will improve (unknown) queries on that view. But the general approach would be a GiST index on the jsonb column and only use JSON operators [that are supported](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING) then hope the condition is pushed down when you query from the view.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. So this is where I am getting stuck.The specifc query needed is (sudo-sql): SELECT listId where productIds contains object with productId = someProductId. I am trying to create an INDEX and VIEW around that, and am struggling with how to achieve that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GIN index on the jsonb column will support [several JSON operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gin-builtin-opclasses.html). One of them is the `@>` operator which also works with JSON arrays.

The following index:

```
create index on product_list using gin (product_ids);
```

A query that can potentially make use of the above index would look like this:

```
select *
from product_list
where product_ids @> '[{"productId": 42}]'::jsonb;
```

---

There is no way your suggested view can make use of an index as the JSONB column is not part of the view and that would be necessary to be able to push down the condition on the JSON column.

The only way you can make use of an index in the view is to include the JSON column in it:

```
create view normalized_list
as
SELECT pl.id AS list_id,
       t.product_id, 
       pl.product_ids
FROM product_list pl
   CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(pl.product_ids) ->> 'id' AS t(product_id)
;
```

A query like this:

```
select id, product_Id
from normalized_list
where product_ids @> '[{"id":42}]'::jsonb;
```

would make use of the GIN index.

---

Note that if you **only** want to store IDs in a denormalized way, a native integer array (`product_ids int[]`) would be more efficient and would make the table substantially smaller

Answer (score 1):

> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html
>
> ```
> {
>     "tags": [
>         "enim",
>         "aliquip",
>         "qui"
>     ]
> }
>
> -- Find documents in which the key "tags" contains key or array element "qui"
> SELECT * FROM api WHERE jdoc -> 'tags' ? 'qui';
> ```
>
> Still, with appropriate use of expression indexes, the above query can
>   use an index. If querying for particular items within the "tags" key
>   is common, defining an index like this may be worthwhile:
>
> ```
> CREATE INDEX idxgintags ON api USING gin ((jdoc -> 'tags'));
> ```
>
> Now, the `WHERE` clause `jdoc -> 'tags' ? 'qui'`
>
> will be recognized as an
>   application of the indexable operator `?` to the 
>   indexed expression `jdoc-> 'tags'`.

So if you will change structure from

```
'[{ "productId":0 }, { "productId":0 }]'
```

to

```
'{"productIds": ["0", "1"]}'
```

or even

```
'{"products": {"0": {"title": "aaa"}, "1": {"title": "bbb"}}}'
```

you can build proper index